# How to compile and build C++ projects with Ant?

Tags: java, c++, ant, compilation, linker

I have several Java components all are built by Ant, however I would like to add one more component (written in C++) and compile/build it in Ant as well.

Is there a tutorial which I can follow or a short way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `make` as [ant exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)
You can pass env variables to the make

```
<exec executable="make" dir="${cpp.project.dir}">
    <env key="KEY" value="VALUE"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ant is ancient, but you still can do this with a lot of pain.

I would recommend to use modern build system [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) which has C++ support as well. You can find tutorials on [their web-site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, and I understand, however the decision is given by someone else, not me. Therefore I do need the ancient stuff running.

Comment: What's wrong with Make? If not triggered externally, I would not understand the choice.

Comment: @chatraed: Nothing is wrong with Make, you can explain how to call make from ant script in your answer - it seems this is what OP wants. Still Gradle is very useful when you have Java project and need to use some native code in C++, and obviously need to use 1 build system for both languages. For pure C++ project there are better alternatives than Gradle.

Comment: @nogard Exactly, this. I would be glad if someone could give a tutorial website about it, or if it is too easy to handle, one can tell how as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not the first trying to accomplish this kind of task:

- [Building C++ projects with ANT](http://codemesh.com/products/junction/doc/ant_cpp.html)
- [Axis C++ ANT Build Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/antbuild-guide.html)
- [cpptasks for Apache Ant](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="hello" default="compile">
    <taskdef resource="cpptasks.tasks"/>
    <target name="compile">
        <cc outfile="main" objdir="obj" outtype="executable">
            <fileset dir="./" includes="*.cpp"/>
            <compiler id="Linuxgcc" name="g++">
                <compilerarg value="-fPIC"/>
            </compiler>
            <linker id="LinuxLinker" name="g++" libtool="true">
                <linkerarg value="-g" if="debug"/>
                <linkerarg value="-fPIC"/>
                <libset libs="stdc++"/>
            </linker>
        </cc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Make sure you place cpptasks.jar(http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcpptasksjar.htm) in your ant's lib folder